# JavaScript - webkitSpeechRecognition, endless listening

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I am doing webkitSpeechRecognition with JavaScript, and it's doing great, but I am facing a problem: I want my speech recognition to start when loading the page always on, and after every word, print it on console log.

I could not make my program to print every word even though I tried with while and so.

Here what I came up with so far:

```
<script>
    function startDictation() {
        if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {

            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

            recognition.continuous = true;
            recognition.interimResults = false;

            recognition.lang = "en-US";
            recognition.start();
            recognition.onresult = function(e) {
                //recognition.stop();
                understand(e.results[0][0].transcript);
            };

            recognition.onerror = function(e) {
                //recognition.stop();
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = startDictation;
    function understand(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        //startDictation();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
 recognition.interimResults = false;
```

with

```
 recognition.interimResults = true;
```

You need to set interim results to true. It may not give you word by word but will give phrases as they are recognized. You can see more at: 
[Voice Driven Web Apps: Introduction to the Web Speech API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API)